# Using ModelNotFoundException

Tags: laravel

I'm starting out in Laravel and want to discover more about using error handling especially the `ModelNotFoundException` object.

```
<?php
 class MenuController extends BaseController {

    function f() {
          try {
                $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();
            } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
                $message = 'Invalid parent_id.';
                return Redirect::to('error')->with('message', $message);
            }
        return $menus;
    }
  }
?>
```

In my model:

```
<?php
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;  

 class Menu extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'categories'; 
}

?>
```

Of course for my example there are no records in 'categories' that have a `parent_id > 100` this is my unit test. So I'm expecting to do something with `ModelNotFoundException`.

If I run http://example.co.uk/f in my browser I receive:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ ModelNotFoundException
No query results for model [Menu].
```

the laravel error page - which is expected, but how do I redirect to my route 'error' with the pre-defined message? i.e.

```
<?php
// error.blade.php

{{ $message }}
?>
```

If you could give me an example.

Comment: I think you should return a Response::view with a 404 header, instead of redirecting to a different page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `Laravel` by default there is an error handler declared in `app/start/global.php` which looks something like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code) {
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

This handler basically catches every error if there are no other specific handler were declared. To declare a specific (only for one type of error) you may use something like following in your `global.php` file:

```
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception) {

    // Log the error
    Log::error($exception);

    // Redirect to error route with any message
    return Redirect::to('error')->with('message', $exception->getMessage());
});
```

it's better to declare an error handler globally so you don't have to deal with it in every model/controller. To declare any specific error handler, remember to declare it after (bottom of it) the default error handler because error handlers propagates from most to specific to generic.

Read more about [Errors & Logging](http://laravel.com/docs/errors).

Comment: I think he should return a Response::view with a 404 header, instead of redirecting to a different page

Comment: but sometimes you know your controller will only fail at some point. And at that point, you want them to return to where user was before (or to a particular url), or just send a customized AJAX error to browser.

Comment: I agree with this answer. But, I'm wondering if a global error handler is really better than local ones. Because I think (and here I'm thinking more on the user experience) that a message related with the action that the user was doing is better than a generic message. I'm looking for a way to do it using global handlers but until now I haven't found it

Answer (score 12):

Just use namespace

```php
try {
    $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();
}catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    $message = 'Invalid parent_id.';
    return Redirect::to('error')->with('message', $message);
}
```

Or refer it to an external name with an alias

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, my response is directly passed to the Handler, skipping my custom message.

Comment: maybe your code is namespaced, add a backslash in front in this case (answer updated)

Comment: Worked for me in Laravel 5.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you use the `render()` function in Laravel 8.x and higher versions, you will encounter `500 Internal Server Error`. This is because with Laravel 8.x errors are checked within the `register()` function (Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64245534/render-function-in-handler-php-not-working-laravel-8))

I'm leaving a working example here:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function register()
    {

        $this->renderable(function (ModelNotFoundException $e, $request) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Model not found'], 404);
        });
        $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Data not found'], 404);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately ModelNotFoundException renderable not working in Laravel 9. we need to do it as like https://stackoverflow.com/a/75492554/14344959 this answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  try {

      $user = User::findOrFail($request->input('user_id'));

    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {

       return back()->withError($exception->getMessage())->withInput();
    }
```

And to show error, use this code in your blade file.

```
 @if (session('error'))
   <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ session('error') }}</div>
 @endif
```

And of course use this top of your controller

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
```