# render function in Handler.php not working Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to return a JSON response instead of the default 404 error page when **ModelNotFoundException** occurs. To do this, I wrote the following code into `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` :

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Resource not found'
        ], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

However it doesn't work. When the **ModelNotFoundException** occurs, Laravel just shows a blank page. I find out that even declaring an empty render function in `Handler.php` makes Laravel display a blank page on **ModelNotFoundException**.

How can I fix this so it can return JSON/execute the logic inside the overriden render function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Laravel 8x, You need to `Rendering Exceptions` in `register()` method

```
use App\Exceptions\CustomException;

/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (CustomException $e, $request) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    });
}
```

For `ModelNotFoundException` you can do it as below.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
        return response()->json(...);
    });
}
```

By default, the Laravel exception handler will convert exceptions into an HTTP response for you. However, you are free to register a custom rendering Closure for exceptions of a given type. You may accomplish this via the `renderable` method of your exception handler. Laravel will deduce what type of exception the Closure renders by examining the type-hint of the Closure:

More info about the [error exception](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Why do you have to use `NotFoundHttpException` exception in the handler for a `ModelNotFoundException`? I have an issue where the `NotFoundHttpException` is also thrown for 404 errors but I want to throw different errors for these exceptions

Answer (score 8):

This code doesn't work for me (in Laravel 8.74.0):

```
$this->renderable(function (ModelNotFoundException$e, $request) {
    return response()->json(...);
});
```

Don't know why, but `ModelNotFoundException` is directly forwarded to `NotFoundHttpException` (which is a part of [Symfony Component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/NotFoundHttpException.php)) that used by Laravel and will ultimately triggers a 404 HTTP response. My workaround is checking the `getPrevious()` method of the exception:

```
$this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
  if ($request->is('api/*')) {
    if ($e->getPrevious() instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 204,
            'message' => 'Data not found'
        ], 200);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 404,
        'message' => 'Target not found'
    ], 404);
  }
});
```

And then we will know that this exception come from `ModelNotFoundException` and return a different response with `NotFoundHttpException`.

**Edit**

[This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L381) is why `ModelNotFoundException` thrown as `NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: This must be accepted as answer on Laravel 8+

Comment: Don't forget to call:    
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

Answer (score 2):

This one is my Handler file:

```
use Throwable;

   public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
 if( $request->is('api/*')){
   if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                $model = strtolower(class_basename($exception->getModel()));
              
 return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Model not found'
        ], 404);
            }
  if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
 return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Resource not found'
        ], 404);
                
            }
}
}
```

This one is only for all request in API route. If you want to catch all request, so remove the first if.

Comment: This didn't work. I wanted it for my api path too so I left the first if but unfortunately its the same blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that by default Laravel emits a JSON representation of an exception ONLY when you send a request with the header parameter `Accept: application/json`! For all other requests, Laravel sends normal HTML rendered output.